# failing to resolve as Trait in Rust in a factorial function

Tags: rust, factorial

In case the reader doesn't' know the factorial function is written to take a u64 type and I'm trying to use a BigUint instead to get bigger numbers with the factorial function.

I'm trying to cast an integer into a BigUint in Rust this is the code I'm trying to change:

```rust
pub fn factorial_iterative(n: u64) -> u64 {
    (1..n+1).fold(1, |p, n| p*n)
}
```

I've just been following rust's handy auto correction and I've come up with this:

```rust
extern crate num;
use num::BigUint;

pub fn factorial_iterative(n: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    (1..n+1).fold(1 as <num::BigUint as Trait>::to_u64, |p, n| p*n)
}
```

but now its throwing me the error: `failed to resolve use of undeclared type or module Trait`

What do I need to add or change to make this work?

Comment: Trait is not a keyword in your code, but a Type or Trait, so the compiler searches for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to get a 1 would be

```
use num::BigUint;
use num::One;

pub fn factorial_iterative(n: u64) -> BigUint {
    (1..=n).fold(BigUint::one(), |p, n| p*n)
}
```

You can't do ranges with the BigUint, so you have to use u64 ranges. You can use the `..=` to get inclusive ranges.`use crate::num::One;` is needed to use `::one()` because its implemented in the `One` Trait which needs to be in scope.

Comment: A slightly less dependent-on-value-of-one example may be to import `num::bigint::ToBigUint` and then call `1.to_biguint()`

Comment: That would work but, its in a mod.rs file and I need to call it into a variable that is using the `use fraction::{Decimal, Fraction};` which accepts a `u64` type and not a `BigUint`. so I want to type cast the input as a `BigUint` but I want the output to be `u64` when you call `n` in the `Decimal::from_fraction(Fration::new(f, factorial_iterative(n)))`.

Comment: otherwise I'm absolutely sure that your answer would work.

Comment: You can convert any u64 into BigUint, by `to_biguint`.
the reverse does not make any sense. If your output would fit into a u64, there would be no need for BigUint

Comment: when I put in `1.to_biguint` it has an error and says to try changing it to `1_i32`. it then says there is no `to_biguint` method.

Answer (score 0):

[@Unlikus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5878876/unlikus) almost had it right. The way I was able to correct the function was:

```rust
use num::one;
use num::{BigUint, One};

pub fn factorial_iterative(n: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    (one()..n+one()).fold(BigUint::one(), |p, n| p*n)
}
```

Thank you. You were able to help me find the right trait to correct my code.

Comment: I had to fix all the rest of my program to use BigUint and all that is left is that `n|` needs a type annotation. I've tried looking it up but, I can't figure out what needs to be done do that.

Comment: if someone wants me to post the entirety of the program file tree let me know.

Comment: Can you post the exact compiler message?

Comment: `pub fn factorial_iterative(n: u64) -> u64 {
    (1..n+1).fold(1, |p, n| p*n)
}
`
This is the code that it is based on.